# SQL Server - Select a column(int val) and 5 times column in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to do something like this in SQL Server:

```
SELECT
    pt.quantity AS 'QTY'
    ,[QTY] * 5
 FROM
 product pt
```

But here I am getting error:
Invalid column name 'QTY'.

Please suggest what could be the issue OR a possible workaround.

Thanks,
Justin Samuel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this will also work

```
SELECT
    quantity AS 'QTY'
    ,quantity  * 5
 FROM
 product
```

you can try this also

```
SELECT QTY,QTY * 5 FROM 
(
 SELECT
        quantity AS 'QTY'   
     FROM
     product) Productstable
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't know how to resolve the name 'QTY' at that point (it would if it was a sub-query for example). Try:

```
SELECT
    pt.quantity AS 'QTY'
    ,pt.quantity * 5
 FROM
 product pt
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
SELECT
    pt.quantity AS QTY,
    pt.quantity * 5 as QTY_BY_5
FROM product pt
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    pt.quantity AS 'QTY'
    ,pt.quantity * 5 AS 'QTY1'
 FROM
 product pt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Alias of the Column for Calculation.
So just replace **'QTy'** with **pt.quantity**, Then it will works.

```
SELECT
    pt.quantity AS 'QTY'
    ,pt.quantity * 5
 FROM
 product pt
```

It would work for you.